# I am getting a warning which is making my page load lazy. "Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event."

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, axios, element-ui

I am getting the warning like "Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event." and suggesting me to "Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive." It quite hard to understand for newbie like me. I am using Axios, mixins, auto-complete in element-ui. The page is working fine, but the loading time is lazy.

Answer (score 0):

It just means you are handling mousewheel events. If the handlers are doing something *instead of* the normal event, you can ignore the message. If you're doing something *in addition to* the normal event, you should add the `passive` option to the listener so the default processing can happen without blocking.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/passive-event-listeners

> In general, add the `passive` flag to every `wheel`, `mousewheel`,
>   `touchstart`, and `touchmove` event listener that does not call
>   `preventDefault()`.

If it's a package that is doing the event handling and not your own code, just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks @Roy J, Is there any relation between the two warnings, 1) mousewheel-event, 2) [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 34ms. I am getting at the end, sometimes it increases upto 80....Which I thought loading time

Comment: If it happens when you're scrolling, then probably yes. Otherwise, no. My guess is probably not. It's likely just something to do with the layout being complicated.